# Linux Bash Script, Single Command But Multiple Lines?

Tags: linux, bash, script, tar

I have the following script I wrote by searching Google, and it backs up my Linux system to an archive:

```
#!/bin/bash
# init

DATE=$(date +20%y%m%d)

tar -cvpzf /share/Recovery/Snapshots/$HOSTNAME_$DATE.tar.gz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/sys --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/media --exclude=/dev --exclude=/share/Archive /
```

This works, but I am wondering if I can format the script to show the command over multiple lines, something like this, so it is easy to edit later:

```
tar -cvpzf /share/Recovery/Snapshots/$HOSTNAME_$DATE.tar.gz 
--exclude=/proc 
--exclude=/lost+found 
--exclude=/sys 
--exclude=/mnt 
--exclude=/media 
--exclude=/dev 
--exclude=/share/Archive 
/
```

That way it is easier to read and edit later. Is it possible to format a Bash script this way?

Answer (score 334, accepted):

All you should need to do is add a `\`(backslash) at the end of each line and it should be good to go.

So yours will look like:

```
tar -cvpzf /share/Recovery/Snapshots/$(hostname)_$(date +%Y%m%d).tar.gz \
    --exclude=/proc \
    --exclude=/lost+found \
    --exclude=/sys \
    --exclude=/mnt \
    --exclude=/media \ 
    --exclude=/dev \
    --exclude=/share/Archive \
    /
```

#### A Few Shortcuts

(based on your comment update for setting $HOSTNAME)

**`$HOSTNAME`**

Two options to set that:

1. Set HOSTNAME

> HOSTNAME=$(hostname)

2. Use command substitution (e.g. `$(command)`)

So it would look like above.  That just makes the command run before using it.

**`$DATE`**

Another variable avoided would be easily:

```
$(hostname)_$(date +%Y%m%d).tar.gz \
```

`$ man date` will have the formats for the date options, the above is YYYYmmdd

Comment: Thanks guys. One last thing. There seems to be a problem with the file name portion of my script:

    $HOSTNAME_$DATE.tar.gz

When I run the script now, the output file is:

    20121120.tar.gz

Comment: If you want your actual "hostname" put it in back ticks (the tilde "~" key above tab):  `/share/Recovery/Snapshots/\`hostname\`_$DATE.tar.gz`

Comment: Anytime @JayLaCroix - Welcome to SU!

Comment: It is [recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4708569/1083697) to use `$(command)` instead of `\`command\``.

Comment: This works with withspaces as a separator. If I have `ssh` on the first line and commands on the following lines, I think I need a semicolon as well besides backslash.

Comment: what do you need to do for the last argument do you still need the `\`?

Comment: Something to watch out for that caught me out and is hard to find by eye sometimes is a trailing space after one of the backslash characters which can cause the command to fail.

Answer (score 26):

Use the backslash to continue a command on the next line:

```
tar -cvpzf /share/Recovery/Snapshots/$HOSTNAME_$DATE.tar.gz \
--exclude=/proc \
--exclude=/lost+found \
--exclude=/sys  \
--exclude=/mnt  \
--exclude=/media  \
--exclude=/dev \
--exclude=/share/Archive \
/
```

Comment: I went back to update it to make it more useful and get the indentations.  I love SU though, by and large.

Comment: This doesn't work for me like eg. in `alias ub='source ~/.bash_aliases \ && source $HOME/.bash_aliases \ && echo "aliases updated."';`

Comment: @TheDefinitionist Sounds like a different problem to this one.  Perhaps open a new question?

Comment: Can I line up the backslashes in a column on the right?

Comment: @SDsolar You can use spaces and tabs to line up the slashes.

Answer (score 22):

You can use this in bash

```
PARAMS=(
    -cvpzf /share/Recovery/Snapshots/$HOSTNAME_$DATE.tar.gz 
    --exclude=`enter code here`/proc 
    --exclude=/lost+found 
    --exclude=/sys 
    --exclude=/mnt
    # this is a comment 
    --exclude=/media 
    --exclude=/dev 
    # --exclude=/something
    --exclude=/share/Archive 
    /
)
# the quotes are needed to preserve params with spaces
tar "${PARAMS[@]}"
```

Comment: Should be `tar "${PARAMS[@]}"`, so that params with spaces get preserved.

Comment: Note that these are just PARAMS for the previous app, if you want to chain it with another action, such as redirecting stout and stderr to a file, that still has to go after. For example, `tar "${PARAMS[@]}" &> my-logs.log`

Answer (score 13):

The same command, but with comments for each line, would be:

```
tar -cvpzf /share/Recovery/Snapshots/$(hostname)_$(date +%Y%m%d).tar.gz `#first comment` \
    --exclude=/proc `#second comment` \
    --exclude=/lost+found `# and so on...` \
    --exclude=/sys \
    --exclude=/mnt \
    --exclude=/media \ 
    --exclude=/dev \
    --exclude=/share/Archive \
    /
```

Comment: This technique is not recommended when performances matter: "note that this technique is expensive because it creates a subshell for each of such “inline comments” during execution. It is only suitable if the commands performance or cost is not a problem." Source: https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-add-inline-comments-for-multi-line-command-in-bash-script/

Answer (score 4):

[Axel Heider](https://superuser.com/users/888845/axel-heider) provided a good alternative to backslashes. Two notes:

1. The command can be included in the list, and
2. The use of the list should be in double quotes `"${PARAMS[@]}"`, so that any spaces in parameters get preserved.

```
#!/bin/bash

params=(
    show
    hello,
    world
    "multi word"
)

function show {
    echo --- Showing \""$@"\" as parameters ---
    for i in "$@"; do
        echo i=$i
    done
}

${params[@]}
"${params[@]}"
```

outputs

```
$ bash test.sh
--- Showing "hello, world multi word" as parameters ---
i=hello,
i=world
i=multi
i=word
--- Showing "hello, world multi word" as parameters ---
i=hello,
i=world
i=multi word
```